# Freeswitch - recorded file is not created under ${recordings_dir} directory

Tags: freeswitch

I am using record application in a custom dialplan. Problem is the recordings doesn't show up in `$${recordings_dir}` which is `C:\Program Files\FreeSwitch\recordings`

```
>> eval $${recordings_dir}:
```

[image]

log shows that it created a file in that directory but after call termination record file doesn't show up.

**Extension:**

```
<extension name="record ivr">  
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^5051$">
        <action application="answer"/>
        <action application="log" data="Start Recording..."/>
        <action application="playback" data="ivr/ivr-begin_recording.wav"/>
        <action application="set" data="playback_terminators=#"/>
        <action application="record" data="$${recordings_dir}/file1.wav"/>
    </condition>
</extension>
```

**Logs:**
[image]

It works fine when I use different folder under different partition `for example: G:\file1.wav` but static path to `recordings` folder doesn't work. I have tried with `base_dir` variable as well but all in vain.

**System**: Windows 7

Please provide some pointers to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check predefined variables:

```
fs_cli -x 'global_getvar'| grep recordings_dir
```

and permissions folder for recording directory.